# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity

Tags: java, android

I've a on screen widget of my app. When this widget is clicked, it opens "DeveloperMode" Setting. But in some devices app is crashing with following message.

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling
>   startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I've tried adding this line by using addFlags and setFlags, but still having same issue. I've viewed previously asked similar questions, but none of them are working.
Here is my `DevModeWidgetReceiver` that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class DevModeWidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, DevModeWidgetReceiver.class), views);

        //without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        //context.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));

        //with set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        /*Intent intent1 = new Intent(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);*/

        //with add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is pretty obvious (and actually classic programming one :)) - you're setting your flag not to newly created `intent1`, but to `intent`, which is being passed as a parameter. So you just have to change this to:

```
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

And then it should work.

Comment: Unbelievable, it was so little mistake. Thanks you, saved my day.

Comment: if you have an AndroidManifest.xml then look for <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" to also help.